# How to create divs / tiles from an sql table

Tags: php, html, css, sql, jquery-isotope

apologies if this sounds noobish, not a lot of experience in web development flash aside, and trying to find the best solution for my project.

I have an sql table from which I can echo data like this in my php file:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>username</th>
<th>objectname</th>
<th>url</th>
<th>description</th>
<th>picture</th>
<th>price</th>
<th>location</th>
<th>category</th>
<th>priority</th>
<th>event</th>
<th>tags</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['objectname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['url'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['picture'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['location'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['priority'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['event'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tags'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

This pulls the whole SQL table for that user. I want to echo the content of each row separately in a separate div so that I can vizualize / echo it using tiles from the isotope jquery plug in. http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

What would be the best way to dynamically generate a number of divs based on the number of rows, and fill them in with each row data?

Again, sorry if this is too broad...

Thanks!

Comment: You need all the fields inside a div or all columns in seperate div?

Comment: Please use literals on english, your text doesn't really looks good without them.

Answer (score 0):

if your sql table id has auto increment then you can use that for div seperation or you can use like below

```
$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<div id='".$i."'>";
  echo "username:" . $row['username'] . "<br />";
  echo "objectname:" . $row['objectname'] . "<br />";
  echo "url:" . $row['url'] . "<br />";
  echo "description:" . $row['description'] . "<br />";
  echo "picture:" . $row['picture'] . "<br />";
  echo "price:" . $row['price'] . "<br />";
  echo "</div>";
  $i++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want rows in different divs then simply

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo "<div>";
  echo "<div>" . $row['username'] . "</div>";
  // SOME OTHER RECORDS
  echo "</div>";
  }
```

additionally you can add ID to divs

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  echo '<div id="sample_'.$row[id].'">';
  echo "<div>" . $row['username'] . "</div>";
  // SOME OTHER RECORDS
  echo "</div>";
  }
```